# angular 5 consoling http toPromise() request returns undefined

Tags: javascript, angular, angular5, angular-http

I am calling an api endpoint in angular 5 using Http import to populate a select dropdown but I am getting undefined when i log it to the console and the dropdown does not populate with any data...its meant to be item categorys.

item-category.ts

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Http, Headers, RequestOptions } from '@angular/http';
import {Router} from '@angular/router';
import { Globals } from '../shared/api';
import { of } from 'rxjs/observable/of';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/toPromise';
declare var $: any;

@Injectable()
export class ItemCategoryService{
    private categoryUrl = this.globals.CATEGORYS_URL;
    constructor(private http: Http, private globals: Globals,  private router:Router) { }

fetchCategories(){
    let v = this.page_header();
    return this.http.get(this.categoryURL, v)
        .toPromise()
        .then(response => response.json())
        .catch(this.handleError);
    };
}
```

itemCategory.component.ts

```
fetchCategorys(){
    this.categorySrv.fetchCategories().then(response =>this.categorys = response.results  )
    .catch(error=> this.error = error )
    console.log(this.categorys);   // <== undefined
}
```

itemCategory.component.html

```
<select class="form-control" [(ngModel)]="product.category"[formControl]="productForm.controls['productCategory']" require>
    <option *ngFor="let item of categorys" [value]="item.slug">{{item.name}}</option>
</select>
```

This is what I have but undefined is what i get in the console and the dropdown has nothing from the api, inspecting shows nothing also...what could I have gotten wrong?

Comment: That's because you are already consuming the Promise in `fetchCategories()` of `ietm-category.ts`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because you're logging `this.categorys` before the response is returned.

try with

```
    fetchCategorys(){
        this.categorySrv.fetchCategories().then((response: any) => {  
               this.categorys = response.results; 
               console.log(this.categorys); // Log here instead of outside the promise  
        })
        .catch(error=> this.error = error )
        // Remove this console.log()
        console.log(this.categorys);   // <== It is correct to be undefined here because it is not in the success promise
    }
```

Also, you need to remove the .then() and .catch() handler inside the service's `fetchCategories()` function. It should just be -

```
fetchCategories(){
    let v = this.page_header();
    return this.http.get(this.categoryURL, v)
        .map(response => response.json())
        .toPromise();
}
```

No need to consume the promise in the service

Comment: Same as before, still undefined @Vandesh

Comment: Can you `console.log(response)` inside the success promise and share the result?

Comment: how do i do that? showing red error when i console.log in the promise

Comment: You need to remove the first console.log() that you had added in your code. Make the changes according to the updated answer and it should work

Comment: done the edit as mentioned but now its throws an error error here
`this.categorys = response.results`

error
**property 'results' does not exist on type 'Response'**

Comment: "property 'results' does not exist on type 'Response'" occurs because you have to type the response. Something like 'then( (response: any) =>' if you don't know the exact type (so you use any, but you better type it with the proper class/interface).

Comment: It could well be the case that there is no results property on your response object. You should try and `console.log(response)` before the line `this.categorys = response.results;` and see if the `response` object contains a `results` property

Comment: `console.log(response)` returns with *headers, status, statusText, type, url and body*

Comment: is this the usual response and do you have an idea why it does not get to the view? thanks for your help so far

Comment: Check the updated answer to map the response to JSON and then check what the response logs

Comment: Oh coool, can see the response in the console now......thanks very much for this.....can you help me check the html if i've got something wrong there? still not displaying in the web page.

Comment: That should be a different problem and a different question

Comment: oops...alright then thank you much for the help. accepting as right answer.

Answer (score 0):

There is no benefit in changing your observable to a promise

Keep the service returning an observable:

```
//service
fetchCategories(){
    let v = this.page_header();
    return this.http.get(this.categoryURL, v)
    .map(response => response.json())
}
```

and in your component, consume it as an observable

```
this.categorySrv.fetchCategories().subscribe( (response: any) => {  
 this.categorys = response.results; 
  console.log(this.categorys); // Log here instead of outside the observable  
}, error=> this.error = error)
```

remember that all http requests (such as this.http.get) are asynchronous, either returning observable or promise. So you only have the proper result before it the value has been emitted (in the case of an observable) or resolved (promise).

Comment: **error**

`Property 'then' does not exist on type 'Observables<any>'`
@ChristianBenseler

Comment: I have made a mistake, had to change the 'then' to 'subscribe'

Comment: yeah thanks for correction, no more error but still undefined in console and nothing in my view